# Exposing and Hiding WCF service contracts

Tags: wcf

Suppose I have 4 service contracts in wcf. I want service1,service2 should be visible for client1 and service3, service4 for client2. How can we achieve this.

Comment: i seriously don't know if answer exists for this. but in my view the service contracts are nothing but interfaces and you want same interface used by the client but at the same time don't allow it to call all methods on it. why not you split the interface ?                                                                                         read this for more info why splitting is good  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle